How to interpret equivalence relations graphically.
Imagine a relation $R$ as a subset of the cartesian product of the real numbers with itself. This relation can be interpreted as a graph.
If R is an equivalence relation

Reflexivity can be interpreted as saying that every point of the line $y=x$ is included.
Symmetry can be interpreted as saying that $y=x$ is an axis of symmetry.

Is this a valid way to interpret relation $R$ if it is an equivalence relation, and if so, how would one interpret equivalence classes and transitivity?

Transitivity is not very natural to describe this way as far as I can tell. It's easier to visualize equivalence relations as partitions of a set into disjoint subsets (namely, the equivalence classes) whose union is the whole set.

It's more useful to think of them as partitions of a set in accordance with the Fundamental Theorem of Equivalence Relations. It's arguably the most important theorem in mathematics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Fundamental_theorem_of_equivalence_relations

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you order elements by equivalence class a block diagonal matrix of co-membership in equivalence relations is the closest visual analogue I can think of.
